# Android Sql Cipher - Migrating from SafeHelperFactory to SupportOpenHelperFactory

Tags: android, sqlcipher-android

I have used saferoom for encryption of Room Db using https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/07/11/introducing-cwac-saferoom.html

Now that we are upgrading to https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-android from https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher, I would like to know if there is any migration available from SafeRoom to SqlCipher.

Need to check if anyone have solved this migration issue.
From the migration guide - https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android-migration/ we can infer that only API changes are required. Does that mean, both are schematically compatible?.

Comment: "Does that mean, both are schematically compatible?" -- they should be the same from Room's standpoint.